# Query to increase salary and save in database

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I want to select an employee and increase his/her salary by 9.5% and   save changes in the database

Query is as followed..I used two related tables Employee_Tbl and Job_Tbl in SQL server 2008

```
SELECT  Employee_Tbl.EmployeeID, 
        Employee_Tbl.Salary,(Employee_Tbl.Salary*5/100)+Employee_Tbl.Salary as       
        SalaryIncreaseByFivePercent
FROM    Employee_Tbl INNER JOIN
                         Job_Tbl ON Employee_Tbl.JobTitle = Job_Tbl.JobTitle
```

I am facing problem to save additional column SalaryIncreaseByFivePercent in database using same query.
Can any body tell??

Comment: you want to save `SalaryIncreaseByFivePercent` into `Salary` column or want to make a new column in Employee_Tbl table and save the increased salary there ?

Comment: I WANT TO MAKE A NEW COLUMN IN SAME QUERY

Comment: Also, what is the percentage. In the opening line of the question you say 9.5%, but elsewhere you say 5%.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use and `UPDATE` statement here. Something like the following will do the trick

```
UPDATE Emplotee_Tbl 
SET Employee_Tbl.Salary = (Employee_Tbl.Salary*5/100) + Employee_Tbl.Salary 
FROM Employee_Tbl AS et 
    INNER JOIN Job_Tbl AS jt 
        ON et.JobTitle = jt.JobTitle 
WHERE Employee_Tbl.EmployeeLastName = "Burns";
GO
```

I hope this helps.

---

Edit. To create a new column called `SalaryIncreaseByFivePercent` and insert the updated salary there, you can merely create the new column using

```
ALTER TABLE table_name
ADD column_name datatype;
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't it is possible to add a column in select query

First add a new column to store increased salary `increasedSalary` of float datatype.

```
ALTER TABLE Employee_Tbl
ADD increasedSalary float
```

Then update the table

```
UPDATE Emplotee_Tbl 
SET increasedSalary = (Employee_Tbl.Salary*5/100) + Employee_Tbl.Salary
FROM Employee_Tbl  t 
   INNER JOIN Job_Tbl  j 
ON t.JobTitle = j.JobTitle
```